# How to set AWS SES identity in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am getting the error message `User arn:aws:iam:blabla:user/blabla is not authorized to preform ses:SendRawEmail on resource arn:aws:ses:locationLblabla:identity/[domain-of-the-to-address].com` my DevOps informs me that `[domain-of-the-to-address]` should me a specific/our domain. The only way I can find to manipulate that is changing the to address. How do i properly set that? I have tried that following

```php
// services.php

return [
  'ses' => [
    'key' => '...',
    'secret' => '...',
    'region' => '...',
    'options' => [
      'SourceARN' => 'arn:aws:ses:locationLblabla:identity/[correct-domain].com'
      'Source' => 'test@[correct-domain].com'
    ],
  ]
];
```

and

```php
// MyMailable.php

$this->withSwiftMessage(function (Swift_Message $message) {
  $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-SES-SOURCE-ARN', 'arn:aws:ses:locationLblabla:identity/[correct-domain].com');
});
```

Edit: In other words. I DO have the `ses:SendRawEmail` permission. I'm sending an email like:
to: joe-bob@gmail.com
from: do-not-reply@my-comp.com

but some how laravel driver or aws sdk is getting it backwards setting my identity as `arn:aws:ses:locationLblabla:identity/gmail.com` not `arn:aws:ses:locationLblabla:identity/my-comp.com` and we don't and wouldn't have an identity setup in out aws for ever single email domain with the `ses:SendRawEmail` so it won't work.

Comment: The error is pretty clear - do you have permission for the `ses:SendRawEmail` action?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary yes, but for a specific identity.

Comment: Is the identity always set as "gmail.com" specifically? If so, do you get it from the error message?

Comment: @WilliamLohan Did you get a resolution to this?

Comment: @Mtxz its always set to the domain of the "to" address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you need the extra config options or the extra text header. It sounds like your SES account is still in the SES Sandbox mode. SES accounts are automatically placed in Sandbox mode when they're created and need to be requested to move out of Sandbox mode.

I'm assuming you've verified the email address or domain you're sending email FROM. However, while in Sandbox mode, you also have to verify the email address or domain you're sending TO. Or, if you can't do that, you can send your test emails to the SES mailbox simulator (success@simulator.amazonses.com).

For more information on Sandbox mode, its restrictions, and how to move out of it when ready, you can visit https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/request-production-access.html.

For more information on the SES mailbox simulator, you can visit https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-simulator.html.

Comment: I'm going to say this is correct as it is now working without extra configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This is an IAM error, can you confirm the IAM user for the AWS Key/Secret you're using has the `ses:SendRawEmail` assigned to it, or alternatively, is there an IAM role granting access to `ses:SendRawEmail` on the Instance/Lambda your code is running from?

Make sure the IAM permission doesn't have any limits against it which could result in it not applying (such as only being applicable to certain servers/tags/IPs/SES identities...).

Sounds like you've verified your domain within SES already, so as long as you've been approved by AWS to leave the Sandbox, then you should be good to send as soon as that IAM issue is resolved.

Comment: If you're still having issues with IAM, could you share your current SES policy JSON?

Comment: This sounds like a request for clarification. That's what comments are for.